# Create trigger to set date time when another column of same table is modified with particular value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to create a trigger in SQL to set the dateTime field to `getdate()` when Status(another column in same table) is updated to '`valueA`'

I am new to triggers. Can someone help me in creating the trigger when column in updated? Problem is I have to check condition on view and update in table

The condition to be checked is:

```
SELECT [Status] FROM [View1] WHERE [Status] Like 'ValueA'
```

if satisfied then,

`DateTime` should be set to `getdate() in [TableA]`

'`ID`' is primary key in the table and view

Thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Sql server

Answer (score -1):

Havent tested this at all and it will prolly throw errors but give it a whirl, it hopefully this will be a good start for ya...

Also this would be for sql server since no dbms was supplied

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_View1] ON [dbo].[View1]
INSTEAD OF Update
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT [Status] FROM [TableA] T, inserted i WHERE [Status] Like 'ValueA' and t.ID = i.ID) 
BEGIN
   UPDATE t
   SET dateField = GETDATE()
      FROM [TableA] T join inserted i on t.ID = i.ID
   WHERE t.ID = i.ID
END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also, this is a bad trigger because if a multi-row update sets *some* row's `Status` to `ValueA` and doesn't do that for *all* rows, this trigger is going to update *all* row's `dateField` values. It should have the conditions for update expressed in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` and shouldn't have procedural logic at all.